# Android WebView no connection when navigating Web page

Tags: android, webview, web, connection, loading

I have an app that loads a website into the [WebView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) for android and up until recently it has been working fine but now it loads and navigates ok but on some page loads it is failed to connect. I can see this from the error message that's built into the app to display there is no connection. Does anyone know what might cause this? I've done some testing and android Oreo devices seem to be fine but slightly older devices do not.

**Main Activity Code**

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebResourceError;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.webkit.DownloadListener;
import android.app.DownloadManager;
import java.io.File;

import android.webkit.URLUtil;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Permission variables
    static boolean ASWP_JSCRIPT     = true;     //enable JavaScript for webview
    static boolean ASWP_FUPLOAD     = true;     //upload file from webview
    static boolean ASWP_CAMUPLOAD   = true;     //enable upload from camera for photos
    static boolean ASWP_LOCATION    = true;     //track GPS locations
    static boolean ASWP_RATINGS     = false;     //show ratings dialog; auto configured, edit method get_rating() for customizations
    static boolean ASWP_PBAR        = true;     //show progress bar in app
    static boolean ASWP_ZOOM        = false;    //zoom in webview
    static boolean ASWP_SFORM       = true;    //save form cache and auto-fill information

    //Configuration variables
    private static String ASWV_URL      = "https://www.centralmanager.co.uk/"; //complete URL of your website or webpage
    private static String ASWV_F_TYPE   = "*/*";    //to upload any file type using "*/*"; check file type references for more

    //Careful with these variable names if altering
    WebView asw_view;
    ProgressBar asw_progress;
    TextView asw_loading_text;
    NotificationManager asw_notification;
    Notification asw_notification_new;

    private String asw_cam_message;
    private ValueCallback<Uri> asw_file_message;
    private ValueCallback<Uri[]> asw_file_path;
    private final static int asw_file_req = 1;

    private SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
            Uri[] results = null;
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                if (requestCode == asw_file_req) {
                    if (null == asw_file_path) {
                        return;
                    }
                    if (intent == null) {
                        if (asw_cam_message != null) {
                            results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(asw_cam_message)};
                        }
                    } else {
                        String dataString = intent.getDataString();
                        if (dataString != null) {
                            results = new Uri[]{ Uri.parse(dataString) };
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            asw_file_path.onReceiveValue(results);
            asw_file_path = null;
        } else {
            if (requestCode == asw_file_req) {
                if (null == asw_file_message) return;
                Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null : intent.getData();
                asw_file_message.onReceiveValue(result);
                asw_file_message = null;
            }
        }
    }


    @SuppressLint({"SetJavaScriptEnabled", "WrongViewCast"})
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (ASWP_PBAR) {
            asw_progress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.msw_progress);
        } else {
            findViewById(R.id.msw_progress).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        Handler handler = new Handler();

        //Launching app rating request
        if (ASWP_RATINGS) {
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { public void run() { get_rating(); }}, 1000 * 60); //running request after few moments
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            //Checking for location permissions
            if (ASWP_LOCATION) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    get_location();
                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
                    show_notification(2, 2);
                }
            }
            //Checking for storage permission to write images for upload
            if (ASWP_FUPLOAD) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 2);
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (ASWP_LOCATION) { get_location(); }
        }
        asw_view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.msw_view);

        //Webview settings; defaults are customized for best performance
        WebSettings webSettings = asw_view.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(ASWP_JSCRIPT);
        webSettings.setSaveFormData(ASWP_SFORM);
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(ASWP_ZOOM);
        webSettings.setGeolocationEnabled(ASWP_LOCATION);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
            asw_view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
            webSettings.setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            asw_view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
            asw_view.requestFocus();
            asw_view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }
        asw_view.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        asw_view.setWebViewClient(new Callback());

        //Rendering the default URL
        aswm_view(ASWV_URL, false);

        asw_view.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            //Handling input[type="file"] requests for android API 16+
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture){
                if(ASWP_FUPLOAD) {
                    asw_file_message = uploadMsg;
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                    i.setType(ASWV_F_TYPE);
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), asw_file_req);
                }
            }
            //Handling input[type="file"] requests for android API 21+
            public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback,WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams){
                if(ASWP_FUPLOAD) {
                    if (asw_file_path != null) {
                        asw_file_path.onReceiveValue(null);
                    }
                    asw_file_path = filePathCallback;
                    Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                    contentSelectionIntent.setType(ASWV_F_TYPE);
                    Intent[] intentArray;
                    if (ASWP_CAMUPLOAD) {
                        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(MainActivity.this.getPackageManager()) != null) {
                            File photoFile = null;
                            try {
                                photoFile = create_image();
                                takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", asw_cam_message);
                            } catch (IOException ex) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "Image file creation failed", ex);
                            }
                            if (photoFile != null) {
                                asw_cam_message = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                            } else {
                                takePictureIntent = null;
                            }
                        }
                        if (takePictureIntent != null) {
                            intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
                        } else {
                            intentArray = new Intent[0];
                        }
                    } else {
                        intentArray = new Intent[0];
                    }
                    Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
                    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
                    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "File Chooser");
                    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
                    startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, asw_file_req);
                }
                return true;
            }

            //Getting webview rendering progress
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int p) {
                if (ASWP_PBAR) {
                    asw_progress.setProgress(p);
                    if (p == 100) {
                        asw_progress.setProgress(0);
                    }
                }
            }
        });




        asw_view.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimeType, long contentLength) {
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));

                request.setMimeType(mimeType);
                //------------------------COOKIE!!------------------------
                String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
                request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);
                //------------------------COOKIE!!------------------------
                request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
                //request.setDescription("Downloading file...");
                request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
                DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                dm.enqueue(request);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });




        if (getIntent().getData() != null) {
            String path     = getIntent().getDataString();
            /*
            If you want to check or use specific directories or schemes or hosts

            Uri data        = getIntent().getData();
            String scheme   = data.getScheme();
            String host     = data.getHost();
            List<String> pr = data.getPathSegments();
            String param1   = pr.get(0);
            */
            aswm_view(path, false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        //Coloring the "recent apps" tab header; doing it onResume, as an insurance
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
            ActivityManager.TaskDescription taskDesc = null;
            taskDesc = new ActivityManager.TaskDescription(getString(R.string.app_name), bm, getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
            MainActivity.this.setTaskDescription(taskDesc);
        }
        get_location();
    }

    //Checking if users allowed the requested permissions or not
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[], @NonNull int[] grantResults){
        switch (requestCode){
            case 1: {
                if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    get_location();
                }else{
                    show_notification(2, 2);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.loc_req, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //Setting activity layout visibility
    public class Callback extends WebViewClient {
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            get_location();
        }

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            findViewById(R.id.msw_welcome).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            findViewById(R.id.msw_view).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        //For android below API 23
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something Went Wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            aswm_view("file:///android_res/raw/error.html", false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something Went Wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            aswm_view("file:///android_res/raw/error.html", false);
        }

        //Overriding webview URLs
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            boolean a = true;

            //Show toast error if not connected to the network
            if (!DetectConnection.isInternetAvailable(MainActivity.this)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please check your Network Connection!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //Use this in a hyperlink to redirect back to default URL :: href="refresh:android"
            } else if (url.startsWith("refresh:")) {
                aswm_view(ASWV_URL, false);

            //Use this in a hyperlink to launch default phone dialer for specific number :: href="tel:+919876543210"
            } else if (url.startsWith("tel:")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(intent);

            //Use this to open your apps page on google play store app :: href="rate:android"
            } else if (url.startsWith("rate:")) {
                final String app_package = getPackageName(); //requesting app package name from Context or Activity object
                try {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + app_package)));
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + app_package)));
                }

            //Use this in a hyperlink to exit your app :: href="exit:android"
            } else if (url.startsWith("exit:")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);

            //Opening external URLs in android default web browser
            } else if (!url.startsWith(ASWV_URL)) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(intent);

            } else {
                a = false;
            }
            return a;
        }
    }


    //Action on back key tap/click
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, @NonNull KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            switch (keyCode) {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if (asw_view.canGoBack()) {
                    asw_view.goBack();
                } else {
                    finish();
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    //Random ID creation function to help get fresh cache every-time webview reloaded
    public String random_id() {
        return new BigInteger(130, random).toString(32);
    }

    //Opening URLs inside webview with request
    void aswm_view(String url, Boolean tab) {
        if (tab) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            asw_view.loadUrl(url+"?rid="+random_id());
        }
    }


    //Using cookies to update user locations
    public void get_location(){
        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
        cookieManager.setCookie(ASWV_URL, "DEVICE=android");
        cookieManager.setCookie(ASWV_URL, "DEV_API=" + Build.VERSION.SDK_INT);
        if(ASWP_LOCATION) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                show_notification(2, 2);
            } else {
                GPSTrack gps;
                gps = new GPSTrack(MainActivity.this);
                double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
                if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
                    if (latitude != 0 || longitude != 0) {
                        cookieManager.setCookie(ASWV_URL, "lat=" + latitude);
                        cookieManager.setCookie(ASWV_URL, "long=" + longitude);
                        //Log.w("New Updated Location:", latitude + "," + longitude);
                    } else {
                        Log.w("New Updated Location:", "NULL");
                    }
                } else {
                    show_notification(1, 1);
                    Log.w("New Updated Location:", "FAIL");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //Creating image file for upload
    private File create_image() throws IOException {
        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
        String file_name    = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_mm_ss").format(new Date());
        String new_name     = "file_"+file_name+"_";
        File sd_directory   = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        return File.createTempFile(new_name, ".jpg", sd_directory);
    }



    //Launching app rating dialoge
    public void get_rating() {
        if (DetectConnection.isInternetAvailable(MainActivity.this)) {
            AppRate.with(this)
                .setStoreType(StoreType.GOOGLEPLAY)     //default is Google Play, other option is Amazon App Store
                .setInstallDays(3)                      //after how many days would you like to show the dialoge
                .setLaunchTimes(10)                     //overall request launch times being ignored
                .setRemindInterval(2)                   //reminding users to rate after days interval
                .setTitle(R.string.rate_dialog_title)
                .setMessage(R.string.rate_dialog_message)
                .setTextLater(R.string.rate_dialog_cancel)
                .setTextNever(R.string.rate_dialog_no)
                .setTextRateNow(R.string.rate_dialog_ok)
                .monitor();
            AppRate.showRateDialogIfMeetsConditions(this);
        }
        //for more customizations, edit AppRate and DialogOptions
    }

    //Creating custom notifications with IDs
    public void show_notification(int type, int id) {
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        asw_notification = (NotificationManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent i = new Intent();
        if (type == 1) {
            i.setClass(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        } else if (type == 2) {
            i.setAction(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        } else {
            i.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
            i.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + MainActivity.this.getPackageName()));
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
        }
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        switch(type){
            case 1:
                builder.setTicker(getString(R.string.app_name));
                builder.setContentTitle(getString(R.string.loc_fail));
                builder.setContentText(getString(R.string.loc_fail_text));
                builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(getString(R.string.loc_fail_more)));
                builder.setVibrate(new long[]{350,350,350,350,350});
                builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
            break;

            case 2:
                builder.setTicker(getString(R.string.app_name));
                builder.setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
                builder.setContentText(getString(R.string.loc_perm_text));
                builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(getString(R.string.loc_perm_more)));
                builder.setVibrate(new long[]{350, 700, 350, 700, 350});
                builder.setSound(alarmSound);
                builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
            break;
        }
        builder.setOngoing(false);
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        builder.setWhen(when);
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        asw_notification_new = builder.getNotification();
        asw_notification.notify(id, asw_notification_new);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState ){
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        asw_view.saveState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        asw_view.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
    }

}
```

Comment: could you please post your code.?

Comment: @Rumit Code has been added. Apologies.